# Is it possible to edit a block with low privileges

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template, slider

My Magento account is not as administrator.

I'm trying to edit an element.

The code I have found in home page in the admin panel for that element is this below

```
{{block type="brands/brands" template="infortis/brands/brand_slider.phtml" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 4], [480, 5], [768, 6], [960, 7], [1280, 7]" timeout="6000" move="1" pagination="1" block_name="I NOSTRI BRAND"}}
```

The element I would like to edit is one link. But you can see that this code is calling a page (`brand_slider.phtml`).

With my account, I can't see that page in CMS between the other pages.

How is it possible to edit that page?

Comment: version are you using?

Comment: my version is 1.9.0.1

Comment: .phtml file is in template folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`brand_slider.phtml` is not a page, it is a template (under a file that mixes PHP and HTML to render blocks).

Thus, you cannot edit this file from the Magento backend (except if you installed a 3rd party module that do this).

You will have to edit the file directly via FTP.

Comment: Do you know some module to advice to me?

Comment: @user1939732 no unfortunately I'm not aware of any but I suggest you use an FTP access directly, ask your administrator for this.